# Implementation Google Maps Polyline and marker together

Tags: google-maps-markers

Hello I have a code where I can see on a map latitude and longitude markers, that code I did following this [tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/probleme-avec-php-bdd-js-xml-api-google) I would like to know how to make each marker is linked with a Polyline

**This is what I have**

[image]

**This is what I want**

[image]

Next I leave my code

```
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-16.342024,-71.540503),
      zoom: 4.0
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('../controlador/test1.xml', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marcadores');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('movil');
          var hora = markerElem.getAttribute('hora');
          var bateria = markerElem.getAttribute('bateria');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));



          var text = document.createElement('text');
           text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });

     var text = document.createElement('br');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
      var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = "MOVIL: "+type
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
       var text = document.createElement('br');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });

       var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = "HORA: "+hora
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });

       var text = document.createElement('br');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });

       var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = "BATERIA: "+bateria+"%"
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });  


          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

(At top of the code below is the XML file from which the markers are created. Copy the XML data into file and name **test1.xml**)
 Any idea how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by following the examples in this [Polyline doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines), you can draw a line on your map connecting different locations.

Here's a sample in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajqp1fLh/) that you can check, which shows 3 locations connected by a polyline.

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = markerPoints; //the coordinates of your markers
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates, //set the path of the polyline to the marker positions
    geodesic: true, //for the polyline to follow the curvature of the earth
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    icons: [
      {icon: lineSymbol, offset: '25%'},
      {icon: lineSymbol,  offset: '50%'},
      {icon: lineSymbol, offset: '75%'},
      {icon: lineSymbol, offset: '100%'},
    ]
  });
```

Please see full code in the sample fiddle. Hope it helps!